# Jquery map function loosing state

Tags: jquery

This is my below code to retrieve the checkbox values using jquery .

```
<div id="checkboxdiv">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value=1 onclick="getVals();" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value=2 onclick="getVals();" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value=3 onclick="getVals();" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value=4 onclick="getVals();" checked/>
</div>
```

Below is the Jquery script function:

```
function getVals(){
  var values=$("#checkboxdiv input[name=test]:checked").map (function (){
    return $(this).val();}).get().join(',');
  alert(values);
}
```

When i execute above code first time ,it is working fine.When i start uncheck any check box
it is giving result like if i uncheck 4th check box ,it is giving result like `,2,3`

I dont understand what is the wrong with above code,Any hints appreciated.

Comment: There's a missing ")" in that code - is that just a transcription error?  (It's the close-paren for the ".map()" call.)

Comment: Also, it should be ":checked", not ".checked" - maybe you should double-check the code to prevent lots of misguided answers, if those typographical errors are not actually present in your real code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works fine **if** you fix these two problems:

1. Add the missing ")" for the ".map()" call
2. The selector should end with ":checked" not ".checked"

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/B5r7u/)

Comment: Sorry for above syntax erros,I am trying with above code only,It is always not taking first checkbox value.

Comment: The jsfiddle I made from your code always seems to work fine. The only differences there are as I describe in the answer above: the missing ")" is added, and ".checked" is changed to ":checked".

Comment: Yes your right,But i dont understand ,why it is missing first index value always in my original code,i checked first index checkbox and it contains value and id are present.Surprisingly some times it retuning first index value also.

Comment: Well, if your code is behaving differently, then the only explanation is that it's different in some way ... I can't see yours, of course, so I can't say what that difference might be. You could try moving your code over to your own jsfiddle and see if you can reproduce the strange behavior you see.

Comment: Working fine with pure javascript.